# jqGrid: what function constructs postData.filters and is it possible to override it?

Tags: javascript, filter, jqgrid, postdata

I use jqGrid with advanced search. For some reason I need to override the function that constructs postData.filters object.

Comment: **Why** you could need to overwrite the construct of `postData.filters`? You mean probably that you want to send *another* parameter as `filters` with your *custom* information, which your backend will use for filtering. Please write in all questions which **version** of jqGrid you use and from which **fork** of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). Which `datatype` you use? Do you use `loadonce: true`? How many rows has your grid (100, 1000, 10000, 1000000)?

Comment: Right you are, @Oleg. I really need to send other values for some types of filter fields. 
The reason of it is the use of JQuery-UI autocomplete plugin. When the user selects one of the autocomplete values in dropdown list autocomplete plugin by default fills input field with the ui.item.value, but the user must see ui.item.label. That's why I override autocomplete select method and put the ui.item.label into filter <input>. But when the postData.filters is sent to server, it must contain values instead of labels for filter fields of such type.

Comment: jqGrid 5.2.0. `loadonce: false`. `rowNum:60`, source DB table has few tens of thousands of rows.

Comment: The last version of "jqGrid" is version 4.7.0. Lather there are exist two main **forks**, base of jqGrid 4.7.0. ["free jqGrid"](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), which I develop, which latest version is 4.15.2 and **commercial** ["Guriddo jqGrid JS"](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334), which develop Tony Tomov and which current version is  based 5.3.0. You use currently **commercial** product Guriddo jqGrid JS. I asked you additional about *total number of rows* in the grid. In case of small number of rows (<1000 or <10000) `loadonce: true` is mostly better.

Comment: Additionally free jqGrid fork supports `<datalist>`, which has build-in support in all modern web browsers. It works very quickly and could be replacement of Autocomplete. See https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/su7ebs65/ and try toolbar search in `Client` column. [Another demo](https://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/performane-13-5000-25-free-jqgrid.htm) can be used to see performance of jqGrid with 5000 rows, 13 columns and 25 rows per page. If you do prefer don't use `loadonce: true` then [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2928819/315935) should help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation, @Oleg. I think I've got all answers I wished to get.

Comment: You are welcome!